# Just can't get this working

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building the UI of my app for now. I can't understand as to what problem is making Eclipse not find the id of my resource.

The `layout.xml` is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".Homescreen" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/playlist" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/homescreen" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Starttime" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="EndTime" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="3dp" />

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/TSSongName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="28" >
    </TextSwitcher>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="30" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/IVRepeat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            **android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBPrevious"**
            android:background="@drawable/media_repeat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/IBPlay"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/player_play" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/IBPrevious"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBPlay"
            android:background="@drawable/previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/IBNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/IBPlay"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IBPlay"
            android:background="@drawable/next" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/IVShuffle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/IBNext"
            android:background="@drawable/media_shuffle" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now the project executes normally if I didn't include the layout position of the `@id/Repeat`. But then if I included it BAAAMM!! it pops out an error saying:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/IBPrevious') AAPT Problem

Comment: add a plus-sign (+) for the reference to the id's:     `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/IBPrevious"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making it:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/IBPrevious"
```

Instead of:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/IBPrevious".
```

Comment: But I just want to refer the current position of Previous, to define that of Repeat that has to placed on the left of it!! I can't understand whats the point in going n creating it again in toLeftOf, OR will it sort this thing out?

Comment: Well thanks @hichris this has done the work! But why does this behave as such in the first place? Very curious!!!

Comment: Does this refer to some back parsing thing going on!!! Wherein it searches for the reference even before it was created???

Comment: it's explained in the first android tutorials. @+ creates the id if it doesn't exist, @ assumes it already exists.

Comment: Very true @coyotte508, but then I found another way round to tackle this I think so!! I guess you all might be knowing this though!!! I just moved the whole tag of Repeat to the last in the (parent) Relative layout!! WOLLA that also worked without making any changes!!